# Website duplicates query string parameters in in-site links

Tags: javascript

I have an issue with IsaFYI.com when Google URL tracking code is used.

For example, if one goes to the page: http://isafyi.com/mom-of-two-covers-college-expenses-with-isagenix-business/then clicks on the recognition link at the bottom of the story, they will be taken to the page http://isafyi.com/category/recognition/. If one were to then click on the link for Sales Promotions, they would be brought to the page http://isafyi.com/sales-promotions/.

```
However, if tracking code is placed on the first page, (in this case, ?utm_source=test&utm_medium=test&utm_campaign=test,) the first url looks like this:

http://isafyi.com/mom-of-two-covers-college-expenses-with-isagenix-business/?utm_source=test&utm_medium=test&utm_campaign=test
```

If one clicks on this link, and now clicks on the recognition link at the bottom of the page, they are brought to

```
http://isafyi.com/recognition/?utm_source=test&utm_medium=test&utm_campaign=test?utm_source=test&utm_medium=test&utm_campaign=test

If you look carefully, you can see that the tracking code is now on the link twice:

http://isafyi.com/recognition/
?utm_source=test&utm_medium=test&utm_campaign=test
?utm_source=test&utm_medium=test&utm_campaign=test
```

If from this page one were then to click on the Sales Promotion link, they would be brought to:

```
    http://isafyi.com/salespromotions/utm_source=test&utm_medium=test&utm_campaign=testutm_source=test&utm_medium=test&utm_campaigtestutm_source=test&utm_medium=test&utm_campaign=testutm_source=test&utm_medium=test&utm_campaign=test
```

The doubled code has been doubled again. This increases exponentially with each click on an internal link.

If a user now clicks on a link leading to an outside site, it is rejected by the server. The message that appears is:

The requested URL was rejected. Please consult with your administrator.

Your support ID is: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

Comment: While those are GA campaign params, this problem has nothing to do with GA tracking or anything GA code does. It is a problem with other code on your site. Likely a botched attempt to passively hook utm codes to the links or similar.

Comment: And it's not a wordpress problem either, so I removed those tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a javascript file "isafy.js". There you have a piece of code:

```
var curUrl = window.location.href; // Gets the url of the current page
    var qs = curUrl.slice(curUrl.indexOf('?utm_')); // Checks url for Google Analytics Query string and if it exists, it is stored in variable 'qs'

    // If 'qs' has 1 character or less it is cleared out
    if(qs.length <= 1){
        qs = ""
    }

    // Goes through every a link on the page and appends the Google query string to every link
    $('a').each(function() {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        href += qs;
        $(this).attr('href', href);
    });
```

This code adds the utm strings but does not check if the parameters have already been appended. So with every clicked link you get another instance of the parameters added to the url (so Crayons comment was spot-on).

I couldn't even tell what this is for - for Google Analytics it's enough if the parameter is set on the landing page. If you need the utm values somewhere else in the page you should consider using a cookie, if not drop this piece of script.